# PHP script returns entire webpage instead of database data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Hi I have a wordpress site and I need to get data from a database and input it in a form.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Wordpress Plugin Stijn 1
Description: Een Wordpress plugin die data uit een database haalt en invult via Ajax in een form.
Version: 1.1
Author: Stijn Aerts
Author URI: http://stijnaerts.be
License: GPL2
*/

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_lookup_userdata' );

function ajax_lookup_userdata(){
    if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        }
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        alert('test');
    jQuery('#input_1_2').change(function(){
            showUser(this.value);
        });
        function showUser(str){
            if(str==''){
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val('niets');
            }
        jQuery.get("getuser.php", { q: str }, function(response){
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val(response);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

and the getuser.php file:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost',****,****,****);
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT Naam FROM Personeel WHERE personeelsNummer = '1'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

return $result

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I test it I get in the text input the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie ie7" lang="nl-NL"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie ie8" lang="nl-NL"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html lang="nl-NL">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Test pagina</title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/xmlrpc.php">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>   <script src="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/js/html5.js"></script>  <![endif]-->
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Test pagina &raquo; Feed" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/?feed=rss2" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Test pagina &raquo; reacties feed" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/?feed=comments-rss2" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Test pagina &raquo; Home Reacties feed" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/?feed=rss2&#038;page_id=2" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css' href='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css' href='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-fonts-css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro%3A300%2C400%2C700%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C700italic%7CBitter%3A400%2C700&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='genericons-css' href='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/fonts/genericons.css?ver=2.09' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-style-css' href='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css?ver=2013-07-18' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-ie-css'  href='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/css/ie.css?ver=2013-07-18' type='text/css' media='all' /><![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
<link rel='next' title='Contact' href='http://test.stijnaerts.be/?page_id=33' />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.9.1" />
<link rel='canonical' href='http://test.stijnaerts.be/' />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://test.stijnaerts.be/' />
<style type="text/css" id="twentythirteen-header-css">
    .site-header {
        background: url(http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/headers/circle.png) no-repeat scroll top;
        background-size: 1600px auto;
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    #wpadminbar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html {
        margin-top: 32px !important;
    }
    * html body {
        margin-top: 32px !important;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 782px) {
        html {
            margin-top: 46px !important;
        }
        * html body {
            margin-top: 46px !important;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body class="home page page-id-2 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support single-author">
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <a class="home-link" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/" title="Test pagina" rel="home">
            <h1 class="site-title">Test pagina</h1> 
            <h2 class="site-description"></h2>  
        </a>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h3>       <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="Naar de inhoud springen">Naar de inhoud springen</a> 
                <div class="nav-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-33"><a href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/?page_id=33">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item"><a href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-41"><a href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/?page_id=41">Registration</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://test.stijnaerts.be/">
                    <label> <span class="screen-reader-text">Zoeken naar:</span>    
                        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Zoeken &hellip;" value="" name="s" title="Zoeken naar:" />
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Zoeken" />
                </form>
            </nav>
            <!-- #site-navigation -->
        </div>
        <!-- #navbar -->
    </header>
    <!-- #masthead -->
    <div id="main" class="site-main">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
                <article id="post-2" class="post-2 page type-page status-publish hentry">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title">Home</h1>   
                    </header>
                    <!-- .entry-header -->
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .entry-content -->
                    <footer class="entry-meta"> <span class="edit-link"><a class="post-edit-link" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&amp;action=edit">Bewerken</a></span> 
                    </footer>
                    <!-- .entry-meta -->
                </article>
                <!-- #post -->
                <div id="comments" class="comments-area">
                    <div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
                        <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Geef een reactie <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/getuser.php/?q=h#respond" style="display:none;">Reactie annuleren</a></small></h3> 
                        <form action="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate>
                            <p class="logged-in-as">Ingelogd als <a href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/profile.php">admin</a>. <a href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.stijnaerts.be%2F&amp;_wpnonce=8100200395" title="Dit account uitloggen">Uitloggen?</a>
                            </p>
                            <p class="comment-form-comment">
                                <label for="comment">Reactie</label>
                                <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>
                            </p>
                            <p class="form-allowed-tags">De volgende <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr>-tags en -attributen zijn toegestaan: <code>&lt;a href=&quot;&quot; title=&quot;&quot;&gt; &lt;abbr title=&quot;&quot;&gt; &lt;acronym title=&quot;&quot;&gt; &lt;b&gt; &lt;blockquote cite=&quot;&quot;&gt; &lt;cite&gt; &lt;code&gt; &lt;del datetime=&quot;&quot;&gt; &lt;em&gt; &lt;i&gt; &lt;q cite=&quot;&quot;&gt; &lt;strike&gt; &lt;strong&gt; </code>
                            </p>
                            <p class="form-submit">
                                <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Reactie plaatsen" />
                                <input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='2' id='comment_post_ID' />
                                <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0' />
                            </p>
                            <input type="hidden" id="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" name="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" value="ff816f89c6" />
                            <script>
                                (function() {
                                    if (window === window.parent) {
                                        document.getElementById('_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled').name = '_wp_unfiltered_html_comment';
                                    }
                                })();
                            </script>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- #respond -->
                </div>
                <!-- #comments -->
            </div>
            <!-- #content -->
        </div>
        <!-- #primary -->
    </div>
    <!-- #main -->
    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div id="secondary" class="sidebar-container" role="complementary">
            <div class="widget-area">
                <aside id="search-2" class="widget widget_search">
                    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://test.stijnaerts.be/">
                        <label> <span class="screen-reader-text">Zoeken naar:</span>    
                            <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Zoeken &hellip;" value="" name="s" title="Zoeken naar:" />
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Zoeken" />
                    </form>
                </aside>
            </div>
            <!-- .widget-area -->
        </div>
        <!-- #secondary -->
        <div class="site-info"> <a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Semantisch persoonlijk publicatie platform">Ondersteund door WordPress</a>   
        </div>
        <!-- .site-info -->
    </footer>
    <!-- #colophon -->
</div>
<!-- #page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        alert('test');
        jQuery('#input_1_2').change(function() {
            showUser(this.value);
        });

        function showUser(str) {
            if (str == '') {
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val('niets');
            }
            jQuery.get("getuser.php", {
                q: str
            }, function(response) {
                jQuery('#input_1_3').val(response);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-includes/js/masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/js/functions.js?ver=2014-03-18'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var request, b = document.body,
            c = 'className',
            cs = 'customize-support',
            rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?' + cs + '(\\s+|$)');
        request = true;
        b[c] = b[c].replace(rcs, ' ');
        b[c] += (window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-') + cs;
    }());
</script>
<div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs" role="navigation">   <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="#wp-toolbar" tabindex="1">Spring naar de toolbar</a>    
    <div class="quicklinks" id="wp-toolbar" role="navigation" aria-label="Topnavigatiebalk." tabindex="0">
        <ul id="wp-admin-bar-root-default" class="ab-top-menu">
            <li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/about.php" title="Over WordPress"><span class="ab-icon"></span></a>
                <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
                    <ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-default" class="ab-submenu">
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-about"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/about.php">Over WordPress</a>   
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-external" class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu">
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg"><a class="ab-item" href="https://nl.wordpress.org/">WordPress.org</a>   
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation"><a class="ab-item" href="http://codex.wordpress.org/">Documentatie</a>  
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums"><a class="ab-item" href="https://nl.forums.wordpress.org/">Ondersteuningsforums</a>    
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback"><a class="ab-item" href="https://nl.forums.wordpress.org/">Terugkoppeling</a>    
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="wp-admin-bar-site-name" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/">Test pagina</a>
                <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
                    <ul id="wp-admin-bar-site-name-default" class="ab-submenu">
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-dashboard"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="wp-admin-bar-appearance" class="ab-submenu">
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-themes"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/themes.php">Thema&#39;s</a>    
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-customize" class="hide-if-no-customize"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.stijnaerts.be%2Fgetuser.php%2F%3Fq%3Dh">Aanpassen</a>  
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-widgets"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/widgets.php">Widgets</a>  
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-menus"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Menu&#39;s</a>   
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-header"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/themes.php?page=custom-header">Header</a>  
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="wp-admin-bar-updates"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/update-core.php" title="3 Plugins bijwerken, Vertalingsupdates"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">4</span><span class="screen-reader-text">3 Plugins bijwerken, Vertalingsupdates</span></a>    
            </li>
            <li id="wp-admin-bar-comments"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/edit-comments.php" title="0 reacties wachten op moderatie"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span id="ab-awaiting-mod" class="ab-label awaiting-mod pending-count count-0">0</span></a>  
            </li>
            <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-content" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/post-new.php" title="Toevoegen"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">Nieuw</span></a>
                <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
                    <ul id="wp-admin-bar-new-content-default" class="ab-submenu">
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-post"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/post-new.php">Bericht</a>    
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-media"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/media-new.php">Media</a>    
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-link"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/link-add.php">Link</a>   
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-page"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page">Pagina</a>  
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-user"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/user-new.php">Gebruiker</a>  
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&#038;action=edit">Pagina bewerken</a>    
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">
            <li id="wp-admin-bar-search" class="admin-bar-search">
                <div class="ab-item ab-empty-item" tabindex="-1">
                    <form action="http://test.stijnaerts.be/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch">
                        <input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" />
                        <input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Zoeken" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account" class="menupop with-avatar"><a class="ab-item" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/profile.php" title="Mijn account">Hallo, admin<img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/36a6b3e27a8b5a0a65cc9ce246ca0256?s=26&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D26&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-26 photo' height='26' width='26' /></a>
                <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
                    <ul id="wp-admin-bar-user-actions" class="ab-submenu">
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-user-info">
                            <a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/profile.php">
                                <img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/36a6b3e27a8b5a0a65cc9ce246ca0256?s=64&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D64&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-64 photo' height='64' width='64' /><span class='display-name'>admin</span><span class='username'>stijnxk59</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit-profile"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-admin/profile.php">Mijn profiel wijzigen</a>   
                        </li>
                        <li id="wp-admin-bar-logout"><a class="ab-item" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=8100200395">Uitloggen</a>  
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  <a class="screen-reader-shortcut" href="http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=8100200395">Uitloggen</a>    
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the first time I'm doing a thing like this, especially in Wordpress and I have no clue what is causing this. I just want the script to work! Lol.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, the getuser.php is not displaying any result. `return $result` is not a valid statement in this case. Maybe you want to iterate over your rowset to display data as JSON ? Second, are your sure your are calling the good URL ? It seems weird that you get HTML by calling getuser.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do is use a browser network inspector to verify exactly what URL is being requested by the $.get() call.  Make sure the URL is correct, and load it up in it's own browser tab directly to troubleshoot the getuser.php file. My guess is that the URL is not correct and you're getting a server or WordPress 404 page, hence the HTML in your response.  It's probably wisdom to use a full URL in your javascript, because pretty permalinks can cause problems with relative URLs like "getuser.php". Better yet, route your ajax request through WordPress's "admin-ajax.php" endpoint, as it's safer (those requests never get cached by plugins, etc), and use a WordPress action to respond to the request.

Then, as Kevin pointed out, the getuser.php file isn't sending any information to the browser.  You'll need to print or echo something to allow javascript to have a response to do anything with.  The easiest thing for you to do would be get your database info in array format and then send it to the browser encoded as JSON, using json_encode( $array_of_data ).  Then, your javascript code easily work with it as a simple javascript object.

Comment: I edited the URL to http://test.stijnaerts.be/wp-content/plugins/StPl1/getuser.php
Now I get this as output:
<br /><b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnaerts.be/public_html/test/wp-content/plugins/StPl1/getuser.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />

I also changed the return $result to echo $result, but this does nothing (so it seems).

Comment: you've likely got a basic PHP syntax error, probably forgetting a semi-colon.

Comment: Yes this was the issue, later on I echo'ed the result as JSON object and parsed it into an array, everything works as intended now, thanks!